# Buscar en campos con entidades HTML

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo un campo en una base de datos MySQL al que le he insertado previamente código HTML; también tengo un buscador que al ingresar la palabra va buscando los resultados. El problema es que los datos en HTML tengo algo como P&uacute;blico que significa Público, y al ingresar el texto en el buscador no me hace el `like` bien.

Por ejemplo, si escribo pú me deja de realizar la búsqueda porque no logra pasar el código HTML a la consulta y poder mostrar los resultados.

Mi código es:

```
<?php

$conexion = new mysqli('localhost','','','');
if (mysqli_connect_error()) { echo mysqli_connect_error(); exit; }
    $q = "%" . $_POST['q'] . "%";

$consulta= $conexion->prepare("SELECT ar.Titulo_Articulo, ar.Id_Articulo, r.Id_Revista FROM articulos as ar INNER JOIN revista as r on r.Id_Revista = ar.Id_Revista where ar.pdf LIKE ?");
$consulta->bind_param("s", $q);
$consulta->execute();
$res = $consulta->get_result();


if($conexion->affected_rows>0)
{
  while($fila=$res->fetch_array())
    {

        echo '<a href="autenticacion.php?id='.$fila["Id_Revista"].'&articulo='.$fila["Id_Articulo"].'" width="50%" class="sugerencias" onclick="myFunction2('.utf8_encode($fila["Titulo_Articulo"]).')"><br>'.utf8_encode($fila['Titulo_Articulo']).'</a>';

    }
}
else
{
      echo '<b>No hay sugerencias</b>';
    }
    $consulta->close();
    $conexion->close();
?>
```

Hola, actualizo mi pregunta, el editor que utilizo es tynimce, copio y pego los datos de un documento de word y al insertarlos en el campo me sale código html, yo lo que necesito es que en el buscador me permita realizar el like en html, he utilizado htmlentities y no funciona $q = "%" . htmlentities($_POST['q']) . "%";

Hola, creo que cometí un error el texto es utf-8 no html,no puedo poner la variable post con html_entities porque es un input, esto tiene que ser en el output pero cuál es?
No, creo que si es en el input, el output no tiene nada que ver desde  la inserción de datos "pú  la letra "ú" la debe convertir a código utf-8, ya he usado utf-8 decode y encode y nada

al final lo he resuelto, el problema es que tinymce tiene su documentación y he puesto como raw el encoding https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/  después he insertado la variable como htmlentities y he logrado buscar con htmlentities y al final he realizado la búsqueda

Comment: El texto HTML lo puedes convertir a UTF8  y guardarlo así, si usas todo en UTF8 no tendrás problemas de esos.

Comment: ¿Por qué tenía yo la impresión de que la cadena guardada era "P&amp;uacute;blico"?

Comment: si, parece que es con http://php.net/manual/es/function.html-entity-decode.php pero sigue sin funcionar

Answer (score 1):

Para buscar con like tienes que hacer el encoding de lo que quieres buscar con htmlentities, como ya te han dicho:

```
 $q = "%" .htmlentities($_POST['q']) ."%";
```

Però es incorrecto salvar los datos en html, es mejor convertir todo antes de guardarlo, y si necesitas los datos html puedes crear dos campos, uno para los datos en raw y el otro solo con el texto para las búsquedas.

Otra cosa, si quieres un 'autocomplete' va bien el like '%%', pero cuidado que es muy lento. 
Si quieres hacer una búsqueda, mejor crear una columna de solo texto y indexarla en formato `FULL TEXT`, para poder buscar de forma mas eficaz y mas rápida:

```
SELECT ar.Titulo_Articulo, ar.Id_Articulo, r.Id_Revista FROM articulos as ar
 INNER JOIN revista as r on r.Id_Revista = ar.Id_Revista 
 WHERE MATCH (ar.pdf) AGAINST (? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

en esta forma también puedes usar el `*` para completar las palabras en esta forma: 'Públi*'

Answer (score 0):

Luis, me llama un poco la atención para que guardar los datos en formato html, si es que necesitas realizar una búsqueda sobre ellos; en este caso tendrías que implementar que al buscar la palabra, esta sea convertida previamente como entidad html usando [**htmlentities()**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlentities.php) , para que de esta forma funcione el query.

Lo comento porque no existe en `MySQL` una función para codificar/decodificar el código html.

Comment: Hola, ya he editado la prgeunta es utf-8 no html :(

Comment: Hola Luis,  en la palabra P&uacute;blico , la letra ú esta códificada como entidad html, esto no tiene que ver con codificación utf-8

Comment: gracias pero aun asi no lo he logrado resolver

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes los datos guardados como HTML entities en base de datos, asegúrate de convertir esos datos a HTML entities antes de pasarlos a tu consulta, te puede valer con hacer:

```
$q = "%" . htmlentities($_POST['q']) . "%";
```

Aunque como te han dicho otros compañeros, es recomendable hacer uso de una codificación UTF8 en estos casos, que usar datos formateados como HTML.

Comment: el caso es que yo tengo un editor de texto en el que copio y pego los datos de un documento de word y al insertarlos en el campo me sale código html, yo lo que necesito es que en el buscador me permita realizar el like en html, he utilizado htmlentities y no funciona     $q = "%" . htmlentities($_POST['q']) . "%";